# CakePHP Images in webroot not displaying in Production

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have pushed my website to Production yesterday, all is working fine with the 3 .htaccess files I created. The only issue is that the images from my webroot folder are not displayed.
I am calling them with **$this->Url->image('pages/' . $page->image)**

Link rendered in html :

background-image:url(/app/img/pages/home.jpg);

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'fr_FR'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Brussels'),
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
    //'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
    'fullBaseUrl' => false,
    'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
    'paths' => [
        'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
        'templates' => [ROOT . DS . 'templates' . DS],
        'locales' => [RESOURCES . 'locales' . DS],
    ],
],
```

/var/htdocs/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What if you add 'fullbase' => true?  e.g. $this->Url->image('pages/' . $page->image, ['fullBase' => true])

Comment: I already tried, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe try moving RewriteBase / to your /app/.htaccess instead of /app/webroot/.htaccess?

Comment: Not working either...:/

Comment: Can you access that file directly? Try `background-image:url("/img/pages/home.jpg");`

Comment: Yes working without the subfolder 'app'... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: look at the app/logs/error.log and tell us what the error message is.

Comment: Have you set `.../app/webroot/` as the hosts document root? What are `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` set to in a request to your app?

Comment: I think I cannot modify the hosts document root with IONOS hostings :/  /kunden/homepages/20/d887310999/htdocs/app

Comment: It might depend on the specific plan, but I have some customers that run projects on IONOS, and AFAIR the document root can be set in the options for the corresponding (sub)domain. That being said, _both_ `PHP_SELF` and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` have that shown hompages path set?

Comment: PHP_SELF : /app/webroot/index.php - DOCUMENT_ROOT : /kunden/homepages/20/d887310999/htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Here is my error Log

2021-10-21 13:18:34 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Img could not be found. in /homepages/20/d887310999/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php on line 226
Stack Trace:

- /homepages/20/d887310999/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:65
- /homepages/20/d887310999/htdocs/app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:311

Request URL: /img/pages/home.jpg